# = operator in java

Tags: java, string, operators

can somebody explain me why it's possible to do:

```
String s = "foo";
```

how is this possible without operator overloading (in that case the "=")

I'm from a C++ background so that explains...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case there is no overloading. The java piece that differs from C++ is the definition of "" - The java compiler converts anything in "" into a java.lang.string and so is a simple assignment in your example. In C++ the compiler converts "" into a char const * and so needs to have a conversion from char const* to std::string.

Comment: Samuel what about it - the question is in effect why is there no implicit or explicit conversion as there woud be in C++ for String s = "foo"; - how would + come in here?

Comment: The compiler converts the series of concatentations into a StringBuffer instantiation followed by append calls with the String objects as mentioned in this answer. 

http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2002/tt0305.html

Comment: Ah I see - string concatination is also detailed in the Java language docs http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: `String` does overload `+`—the one and only case of operator overloading in Java.

Answer (score 1):

This [assigns](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.1) a simple [literal](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5) of type String to `s`

In Java Strings are immutable, if you need to define a constant value you would use the `final` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It is an assignment operator in java which is used to assign the value to the declared type, where no operator overloading is required. Even in c++

Answer (score -1):

[The API says](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

"Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. [String buffers](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) support mutable strings. Because String objects are immutable they can be shared. For example:

```
     String str = "abc";
```

"is equivalent to:

```
     char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
     String str = new String(data);
```