# What is the implementation of ' +' operator of String in Java and where I can see this implementation?

Tags: java

Can any one tell me the exact implementation of '+' operator of String in Java.
As I know this is concat operator to concat two string even then since String is a class then where is implementation of this operator and how it works?

Comment: See this SO question for your answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408427/how-does-the-string-class-override-the-operator

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328483/operator-for-string-in-java

Comment: Try this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 6):

The implementation is compiler-specific, although it usually just ends up creating a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` behind the scenes, and appends to it. Note that it has special treatment for efficiency, so that `x + y + z` can be compiled as something like

```
new StringBuilder().append(x).append(y).append(z).toString();
```

... and also to perform compile-time concatenation of constant string expressions.

You can see the operator *described* in [JLS section 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1), but that doesn't mandate any particular implementation.

To see what your particular compiler does, simply compile some code you're interested in and then use `javap -c` to look at the bytecode it generates.

Answer (score 2):

String `+` may be optimised away by the compiler.  If it is not it is the same as

```
a + b
```

becomes on most JVMs today (older versions used StringBuffer)

```
new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).toString();
```

So StringBuilder.append() is what you want.

Comment: This depends on the compiler.  The JLS allows the compiler to code generate this in other ways.