# Why this is so(see the below two code samples)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Code 1:

```
public void displayQuantity(int number) {
    TextView quantityTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_tv);
    quantityTV.setText( " "+ number);
      }
```

Code 2:

```
 public void displayQuantity(int number) {
            TextView quantityTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_tv);
            quantityTV.setText(number);
         }
```

Why Code 2 gives error while code 1 doesn't??
There is a difference of - " __ " in b/w code 1 & 2

Comment: Code 2 gives error because textview need CharSequence so can't support int value and code 1 not gives an error because + operator automatically converts it into String

Comment: It is because in code 1 you are saying setText( "  " + number) which means you are passing string and in code 2 you are saying setText(number) which means you are passing int instead of string.

Comment: @MaheshVayak  Thanks

Comment: @the_pooran Thanks,It was much easier to get your point

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView)

Code 1 uses the method `setText(CharSequence text)` which "sets the text to be displayed".

Code 2 uses the method `setText(int resid)` which "Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier". Your number most likely is not a valid string resource identifier which gives you an error. Even if it was, the displayed string would have nothing to do with the quantity you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

In `TextView` you can set only `String(CharSequence)` value and your **number** data type is in `int` if you do like this it will not show any error :

```
          public void displayQuantity(int number) {
            TextView quantityTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_tv);
            quantityTV.setText(String.valueOf(number));
         }
```

Comment: Not quite-  setText has an int version-  but it takes a resourceID to a string resource.  And if the id passed doesn't match a string resource, it will throw an exception.  That's what's happening here.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes I wrote this in short way....

Answer (score 0):

number is int type and + operator automatically converts it into String.("" is empty String)

[+ operator for String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328483/operator-for-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try number.toString() in code 2 
because you are doing string concatenation with an int in the